# Normalize a vector?

Tags: vector, normalization

How do you normalize a M*N vector, such that the sum of all its elements is now equal to 1. I browsed online a little, and nothing seems to quite match what I need. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried to find the sum of all elements and divide each element by that sum?

Comment: Little note: The sum of all entries of a vector is only a [norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) if all entries are non-negative. In general you probably want the [sum of the _absolute values_ of your entries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm) to equal 1.

Comment: Yes, I have negative values too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You add up all the elements, then divide each element by the sum.

Obviously, the division (at least) needs to be in floating point. Since that indicates a floating point matrix, doing the summing while maintaining maximum accuracy will be non-trivial.

Just for example, if you have one large element, and a lot of small elements, you'll probably get a more accurate result from adding all the small elements together, *then* adding that sum to the large element, than if you added each small element to the large one individually.

Edit: I suppose I should add that the usual way to deal with this is called Kahan summation, after the high guru of numerical analysis, William Kahan.

Answer (score 1):

i think you have to divide every vector component by the euklidean distance of the vector