# Normalize a vector so all sum of elements add to 1 everytime

Tags: java, vector, matrix, normalization

I am trying to write some code to normalize a vector with elements `[x,y,z]` but was wondering if there is a way to normalize the elements so that each time the sum of elements will add to 1.

I did come across a formula: (pseudo code)

```
normalized = vectorA/ magnitude(vectorA)
```

However, if the `vectorA = [1,4,5]` then using the formula above would give:

```
magnitude = sqrt(1^2 + 4^2 + 5^2)
magnitude = sqrt(42)
magnitude = 6.48
```

Now based on that if I divide each element of the vector by `6.48` then:

```
1/6.48 = 0.154
4/6.48 = 0.62
5/6.48 = 0.77
```

As you can see, the sum is more than 1, so the formula doesn't work everytime and I was wondering if anyone has an idea on how to get the sum of elements to equal to 1 at all times.

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with a diagram:

```
  B-------C
 /|      /|
A-------* |
| *-----|-G
|/      |/
*-------*
```

and let's further state that `AG` is your vector. For simplicity, we'll state that `A` is the origin `[0, 0, 0]`.

If your intent is to simply scale the values (lengths of `AB`, `BC` and `CG`)  in a linear fashion so that they total one, you simply divide each by the sum:

```
/   x       y       z   \
| ----- , ----- , ----- |
\ x+y+z   x+y+z   x+y+z /
```

In your particular case where `x+y+z` gives you `10`, you end up with:

```
[0.1, 0.4, 0.5]
```

which sums up to one.

---

That formula that you found applies to three-dimensional vectors where you want the *length* of the vector `AG` to be one.

And the figures you have for that are (roughly) correct since the length of a vector is:

```
                 2              2            2
  sqrt (   height     +    width    +   depth )

= sqrt (0.154 * 0.154 + 0.62 * 0.62 + 0.77 * 0.77)
= sqrt (  0.023716    +   0.3844    +   0.5929  )
= sqrt (                 1.001016               )

= 1.000507871
```

Plugging your figures into that gives you something close to `1.0005` which is understandable given the rounding of your original numbers.

So, bottom line, if you want the *length* of the vector to be one, simply use the formula you posted in the question. If you want the vector co-ordinates to *sum* to one, just scale them based on the sum of the three co-ordinates.

Comment: Oh my bad! It was a simple solution that I couldnt see. thanks =)

Comment: @user3353723 Here I was typing up my guess-answer based on a lot of fancy theory that I haven't seen in a few years, when this simpler answer pops up. You may be interested in [Wolfram's vector norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorNorm.html) page, particularly the definition of the vector norm (i.e. magnitude). You'll note that setting `p=1` (where I guess `1` corresponds to linear scaling, as paxdiablo mentions) reduces the definition to simply the sum of the vector elements. You were using `p=2`. Even if this isn't revealing anything new to you, maybe it will to someone else later.

Comment: @ajp15243 would be good if you can explain that vector norm in a simpler version of Wolfram. Would really appreciate it man

Comment: @ajp15243 just add your answer on this question and I will give you a +1 too =)

Comment: @paxdiablo what values did you use for height, width and depth?

Comment: @user3353723 As I typed, my answer became just a bunch of intuitive leaps based on the fact that [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10095524/1883647) said to just add the values to find the magnitude, and that the Wolfram page's definition (the equation with the big sigma) reduced to a simple absolute value sum when `p=1`, backed up by [the same simplified equation on Wikipedia's Norm page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#Taxicab_norm_or_Manhattan_norm). I haven't studied these things in a long enough time to give a coherent and sound answer anymore.

Comment: @user3353723, I used the values in your question: `0.154`, `0.62` and `0.77`.