# How can I normalize a vector to sum to a certain value?

Tags: vector, normalization

I have been trying to search for a solution but have not found anything helpful. I want to understand :

How to normalize a vector such that it sums to a certain value?

I am trying to reproduce the results of the paper: 
Designing human agents that act like human agents: A Behavioural approach to bounded rationality by W.Brian Arthur (1991).

On page 354 of this paper four points are mentioned, my doubt is limited to the 4th point. I can not understand how to calculate the 4th point.

For the sake of convenience I will write the entire 4th point preceded by the previous 3 points.

PROBLEM DESCRIPTION:

Set of N actions exist, from 1 to N. A vector of strength S_t is associated with every action at every time 't'. The current sum of these strength is C_t (the component sum of S_t) and the initial vector S_0 is strictly positive. The probability p_t represents the agent's probablities of taking actions 1 through N at time t.

At each time t, the agent:
1. Calculates the probablity vector as the relative strengths associated with each action. It sets, p_t = (S_t/C_t)

2. Chooses one action from the set according to the probablities p_t and trigger that action.
3. Observes the payoff received and updates strengths by adding the chosen action j's payoffs to action j's strength. That is, where action j is chosen, it sets the strength to S_t + beta. Where, beta = payoff(j)*e_j
   (e_j is the jth unit vector)
4. Renormalizes the strengths to sum to a value from a prechosen time sequence. In this case, it renormalizes strength to sum to C_t = C*t.
   (Where t could also be raised to a value v)

QUESTION: I dont understand how to renormalize the strength to a sum ?

Furthermore, I have read this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095524/normalize-a-vector):

Comment: I think the detailed version of the question would be very useful here.

Comment: Isn't this question for http://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: "Sums to a certain value", you mean that the components summed would be 2? Usually normalization handles the length of the vector and doesn't care about the sum of the components, so I don't think that's the correct term. But if you just want to make sure they add up to two, then multiply every component by 2 and divide by the sum of the original components.

Comment: @RobAston I have edited the question and given a detailed description. Please take a look.

Comment: @ Sami Kuhmonen: I have edited the question, if possible could you pls take a look because I am not quite sure about what you said.

Comment: @ Andriy: No, I didnt post any question on math.stackexchange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you really only need to make sure the component sum of the vector is X. It is simple.

If we have a vector `V = [a, b, c, d]`, it's component sum `S` is of course `S = a+b+c+d`. If this has to add up to value `X`, then we can simply multiply both sides with `X` to get `S*X = (a+b+c+d)*X`, move S to the other side to get `X = (a+b+c+d)*X/S`.

So now we know how to get X: every part of the vector has to be multiplied with X and divided by the current sum of the components:

```
a' = a*X/S
b' = a*X/S
c' = a*X/S
d' = a*X/S
```

Then we get the new vector `V' = [a', b', c', d']` and its component sum will be `X` and the relative weights will be unchanged.

Comment: Thanks a ton. I did this yesterday but just wanted to be sure, now that you explained it so precisely, I know what I understood from your answer was right. Thanks once again..!!!